# PHP comparing two Date Time ranges

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have two date ranges one of the ranges `Start_Time` and `End_Time` is coming from MYSQL database and other (user) range is on every day from `6 p.m` to `5 a.m`

Now I am trying to compare two ranges and make sure user enters -start time- (`6p.m` to `5 a.m` next day) does not fall in "`Start_Time`" and "`End_Time`" and vice versa.

Same is also true with database `End_Time` and user's *start time* and *end time*.

Code:

1. Create a format of start and end time of user date but everyday time is constant (`6 p.m` to next day `5 a.m`)
   User Range (for example):

```
User Start Time:...... 2015-04-18 18:00:00
User End Time:2015-04-19 05:00:00
```

Within the database:

```
MySQL DB Start Time:............ 2015-04-19 00:50:00
MySQL DB End Time:....2015-04-19 23:50:00
```

For user dates time range is always between `6p.m` to `5p.m`. Only we have to modify the date.

To achieve user required range:

```
$sttime="18:00:00";
$ettime="05:00:00";
$teststartdate = date("Y-m-d");

$teststartdatetime=$teststartdate." ".$sttime;

#Calculate Endtime
#$testendtime=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($teststartdate . ' + 1 day'))." ".$ettime;
```

For comparison, I wrote a function but looks like this is not always working:

```
function dateIsBetween($dbfrom1,$dbto1,$user_st,$user_et) {

    $from = strtotime($dbfrom1);
    $to = strtotime($dbto1);  
    $st = strtotime($user_st);
    $et = strtotime($user_et);
    echo "DB FROM:............ ".$from.PHP_EOL."DB TO:....".$to.PHP_EOL."ST Start Time:...... ".$st.PHP_EOL."ST End Time:".$et;
      if (('$from' >= '$st' && '$from' < '$et') || ('$to' >= '$st' && '$to' <= '$et') || ('$from' <= '$st' && '$to' > '$et')) {      
        return 1;
      }else {return 0;}
```

If the user date (start date or end date) falls within database range, I need to print "Busy".
This logic works sometime, sometime it does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may have oversimplified this, but in my 3 test scenarios, as limited as they might be, are working.

```
var_dump(dateIsBetween('2015-04-01 14:00:00', '2015-04-02 05:00:00', '2015-04-01 08:00:00', '2015-04-01 10:00:00'));
var_dump(dateIsBetween('2015-04-01 14:00:00', '2015-04-02 05:00:00', '2015-04-01 18:00:00', '2015-04-01 19:00:00'));
var_dump(dateIsBetween('2015-04-01 14:00:00', '2015-04-02 05:00:00', '2015-04-01 08:00:00', '2015-04-02 05:00:00'));

function dateIsBetween($dbfrom1,$dbto1,$user_st,$user_et) {

    if(((strtotime($user_st) >= strtotime($dbfrom1)) and (strtotime($user_st) <= strtotime($dbto1))) or (strtotime($user_et) >= strtotime($dbfrom1)) and (strtotime($user_et) <= strtotime($dbto1))) {

        return true;

    } else {

        return false;   

    }

}
```

EDIT

I believe I had the params of the method backwards after re-reading.

Try this:

```
var_dump(dateIsBetween('2015-04-01 08:00:00', '2015-04-01 10:00:00', '2015-04-01 14:00:00', '2015-04-02 05:00:00'));
var_dump(dateIsBetween('2015-04-01 18:00:00', '2015-04-01 19:00:00', '2015-04-01 14:00:00', '2015-04-02 05:00:00'));
var_dump(dateIsBetween('2015-04-01 08:00:00', '2015-04-02 05:00:00', '2015-04-01 14:00:00', '2015-04-02 05:00:00'));

function dateIsBetween($dbfrom1,$dbto1,$user_st,$user_et) {


    if(((strtotime($dbfrom1) >= strtotime($user_st)) and (strtotime($dbfrom1) <= strtotime($user_et))) or (strtotime($dbto1) >= strtotime($user_st)) and (strtotime($dbto1) <= strtotime($user_et))) {

        return true;

    } else {

        return false;   

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Michael for your answer.
I have copy pasted your code and echo all the variables in a function before strtotime and looks like it is not working:

dbfrom1:: 2015-04-19 22:31:00
dbto1:: 2015-04-19 23:31:00
user_st:: 2015-04-19 18:00:00
user_et::2015-04-20 05:00:00

Below is the code that i tweaked little bit:

Comment: You echoed all the variables before the strtotime?  You will need strtotime to convert to the unix timestamp to properly do you comps.  Did you verify my results with the test time frames I gave?

Comment: function dateIsBetween($dbfrom1,$dbto1,$user_st,$user_et) {
echo "dbfrom1:: ".$dbfrom1.PHP_EOL."dbto1:: ".$dbto1.PHP_EOL."user_st:: ".$user_st.PHP_EOL."user_et".$user_et.PHP_EOL;
    if(((strtotime($user_st) >= strtotime($dbfrom1)) and (strtotime($user_st) <= strtotime($dbto1))) or (strtotime($user_et) >= strtotime($dbfrom1)) and (strtotime($user_et) <= strtotime($dbto1))) {
        return 1;
    } else { return 0; }

Comment: Thanks again for looking but it is still not working for the below dates:
it should print Busy as per the user dates:
Also i have echoed before strtotime. My time combination is:
dbfrom1:: 2015-04-19 22:31:00
dbto1:: 2015-04-19 23:31:00
user_st:: 2015-04-19 18:00:00
user_et::2015-04-20 05:00:00

Comment: Looks like "Edited version" is working. I did copy paste error.
Sorry again.

Comment: Good to hear!  Hope your project goes well!